# email notification using console application with c#

Tags: c#, console

i am, developing an application which trigger email on 2nd 3rd and 4th working day of current month i.e. if 2nd working day will be Saturday then application will trigger email on next weekday and it will be Monday.

can it will be possible using task scheduler or window services?

Comment: Suggest what exactly.?Please be more ellaborate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you could [show us what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that'd be wonderful. Also, while we're at it, please do check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's considered on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: i a, developing an application which trigger email on 2nd 3rd and 4th working day of current month i.e. if 2nd working day will be Saturday then application will trigger email on next weekday and it will be Monday.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand this correct, you need an application which will trigger emails on the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th of the current month. If anyone of these days falls on Saturday or Sunday, email will go out on the next working day.

Answering your question, I am not sure if this can be done using Task scheduler. You will probable need an application ( c# console for example) which will take care of sending email, checking if the day is Weekend, and resume it on next working day. You can schedule this task to run for the first week of every month(this should be your choice weather you want to run it every day or just on the first week of current month). This is not a full proof solution for your problem, but it will at least give you some directions.